# Array.prototype.map.call Why does it keep returning 0?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to use Array.prototype.map.call to pull a list of text entries from an unordered list. I am generating the list from dropdown selections (each selection adds a new `<li>` to the list. When I submit the form, I want it to identify all the items in the list and add them with commas separating.

Currently, when I submit the form, all I return are a bunch of 0s (separated by commas).

(Building this in Google Apps Script to create a custom form in a Spreadsheet)

Here's what I'm using:

```
var teacherNameValues = teacherName.length === 0 ? "" : Array.prototype.map.call(teacherName,function(n) { return n.value }).join(", ");
```

My empty unordered list is id "currentTeachers"

The rest of what I am using is below. All the other fields listed are functioning correctly--ONLY the teacherName is recording 0s instead of text.

```
      var arrayOfDistrictsBuildings;  

      function afterButtonSubmit() {
        var meetingDate = document.getElementById("enterDate");
        var cbdCoach = document.getElementById("selectCoach");
        var districtName = document.getElementById("selectDistrict");
        var buildingName = document.getElementById("selectBuilding");
        var teacherName = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
        var meetingProductivity = document.getElementById("selectProductivity");
        var generalNotes = document.getElementById("generalNotes");

        var teacherNameValues = teacherName.length === 0 ? "" : Array.prototype.map.call(teacherName,function(n) { return n.value }).join(", ");

        var rowData = {
                      meetingDate: meetingDate.value, 
                      cbdCoach: cbdCoach.value, 
                      districtName: districtName.value, 
                      buildingName: buildingName.value,
                      teacherName: teacherNameValues, 
                      meetingProductivity: meetingProductivity.value, 
                      generalNotes: generalNotes.value
                      };
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterFormSubmit).addNewRow(rowData);
      }

      function afterFormSubmit(e) {
        var districtName = document.getElementById("selectDistrict");
        districtName.value = "";
        var buildingName = document.getElementById("selectBuilding");
        buildingName.value = "";
        var teacherName = document.getElementById("selectTeacher");
        teacherName.value = "";        
        var generalNotes = document.getElementById("selectProductivity");
        selectProductivity.value = "";
        var generalNotes = document.getElementById("generalNotes");
        generalNotes.value = "";
      }

      function afterSidebarLoads(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterCbdCoachReturned).getCbdCoachOptions();
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterDistrictReturned).getDistrictOptions();
      }

      function addUniqueItemsToLists(el,districtLoop,index){
        var currentlyAdded = [];
        el.innerHTML = '<option>select here</option>';
        districtLoop.forEach(function(r){
          if(currentlyAdded.indexOf(r[index]) === -1){
          var districtOption = document.createElement("option");
          districtOption.textContent = r[index];
          el.appendChild(districtOption);
          currentlyAdded.push(r[index]);
          };
        });
      }
//get Coach from list
     function afterCbdCoachReturned(coachLoop){
        var cbdCoach = document.getElementById("selectCoach");
        
        coachLoop.forEach(function(r){
          var coachOption = document.createElement("option");
          coachOption.textContent = r[0];
          cbdCoach.appendChild(coachOption);
        });

      }

//get school district from list and filter based on number of instances
      function afterDistrictReturned(districtLoop){
        arrayOfDistrictsBuildings = districtLoop.filter(function(r){ return true; });
        var districtName = document.getElementById("selectDistrict");
        addUniqueItemsToLists(districtName,arrayOfDistrictsBuildings,0);
        document.getElementById("loading").remove();
      }

      function afterDistrictSelected(){
        var buildingName = document.getElementById("selectBuilding");
        var teacherName = document.getElementById("selectTeacher");  
        var districtName = document.getElementById("selectDistrict").value;
        var filteredDistricts = arrayOfDistrictsBuildings.filter(function(r){ return r[0] === districtName; });
        addUniqueItemsToLists(buildingName,filteredDistricts,1);
        addUniqueItemsToLists(teacherName,filteredDistricts,2);

      }

      var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
        var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
        var txt = document.createTextNode("(remove)");
        span.className = "close";
        span.appendChild(txt);
        myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
      }

      var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        close[i].onclick = function() {
          var div = this.parentElement;
          div.style.display = "none";
        }
      }

      function newElement() {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var inputValue = document.getElementById("selectTeacher").value;
        var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
        li.appendChild(t);

        document.getElementById("currentTeachers").appendChild(li);
        document.getElementById("selectTeacher").value = "";

        var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
        var txt = document.createTextNode("(remove)");
        span.className = "close";
        span.appendChild(txt);
        li.appendChild(span);

        for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
          close[i].onclick = function() {
            var div = this.parentElement;
            div.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }

      document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener("click",afterButtonSubmit);
      document.getElementById("selectDistrict").addEventListener("change",afterDistrictSelected);
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",afterSidebarLoads);
```

Comment: `<li>` tags don't have `.value`, that's only for inputs. You might want `.innerText` depending on your goal. Also you don't need the `0` length check. Here's a cleaner version: ```const teacherNameValues = Array.from(teacherName).map(li => li.innerText).join(", ")```

Comment: You don't need to use `Array.prototype.map.call()` in modern JS. Use either `Array.from(teacherName).map` or `[...teacherName].map`

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Now I have to figure out how to get it to remove a list item when I select "remove"...